# Zend Framework: Change color of Zend Validation message

Tags: zend-framework, validation, colors, zend-form

Is there a way to change to color of the message after Zend validation?

This is my code right now:

```
        $name = $this->createElement('text', 'name');
    $name->setLabel('Name:')
            ->setAttrib('size', 50)->addValidator('StringLength', false,array(2,30))
                            ->addValidator($validator)
```

The $validator checks if the first letter is a capital letter.

Could I add some code to make the Validation text red? So if it is filled incorrectly, the message is in red color?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend validation error messages draws like..

```
<ul class="errors">
<li>Error Message 1</li>
<li>Error Message 2</li>
<li>Error Message 3</li>
</ul>
```

So declare a class in css for ul.errors and specify color for that.

Answer (score 1):

Some decorators allows you to configure them and set options :

```
$name->getDecorator('Errors')->setOption('class', 'custom_form_errors');

.custom_form_errors {
    list-style: none;
    ....
}
```

(I answer a bit late but since I was wondering the same question...)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class in css called ul.errors

```
ul.errors {
    color: color_code;
}
```